# Understanding the expected value of the average

Tags: options, derivatives, geometric-brownian, asian-option

I've been looking into Asian Options pricing. Part of the process is about looking for the expected value of the average of a time series undergoing e.g. geometric brownian motion.

I came across this paper: [*Pricing and hedging of arithmetic Asian options via the Edgeworth series expansion approach*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405918816300022).

In the appendix, they claim to calculate the expected value of the average over a time period, see screenshot below:

[image]

I find this quite problematic, in that this value seems like it would necessarily be before the initial value, even if the drift of the underlying asset is assumed to be 0. It seems un-intuitive to say that the average must have a greater expected value than the initial value.

Furthermore, this value doesn't match what I get for the expected value when simulating as much as 10,000,000 price paths, but even more concerning perhaps is that the result from random simulations is still above the initial price.

I tested with the following parameters. Time to maturity: 0.25 years. Initial price: 1000. Underlying annualized volatility: 0.7. Underlying drift: 0

Would anyone happen to have an idea of what is going on here? Thanks.

Comment: When you say you set the drift equal to zero - do you still have a risk free rate in there?

Comment: @rubikscube09 Good point, I didn't pay enough attention. I wanted to set the risk free interest rate to 0 in the risk neutral measure. In this case it seems that mu0 is just -sigma0**2/2. Which doesn't really help us because now the formula for the expected value of the average given is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math checks out, and a carefully conducted simulation study will follow the result:

For $S_t$ following a geometric Brownian motion with constant parameters $\mu,\sigma$,we know that $$E(S_T|S_t)=S_te^{(\mu+0.5\sigma^2)(T-t)}$$

In this case, the risk neutral drift $\mu_{\mathbb{Q}}=r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2$, hence the risk-neutral expectation of $S_t$ at any future time (simply) becomes its forward level:

$$
Y(T)\equiv E_\mathbb{Q}(S_T|S_t)=S_te^{(\mu_{\mathbb{Q}}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)}=S_te^{r(T-t)}
$$

Now integrating $Y(s)$ with respect to $s$ clearly yields the stated result,

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{T-t}\int_{s=t}^T Y(s)ds&=\frac{1}{T-t}\int_{s=t}^T E_\mathbb{Q}(S_s|S_t)ds\\
&=\frac{S_t}{T-t}e^{-rt}\int_{s=t}^T e^{rs}ds\\
&=\frac{S_t}{T-t}e^{-rt}\left[\frac{e^{rs}}{r}\right]_t^T\\
&=\frac{S_t}{T-t}e^{-rt}\left(\frac{e^{rT}}{r}-\frac{e^{rt}}{r}\right)\\
&=\frac{S_t}{T-t}\left(\frac{e^{r(T-t)}-1}{r}\right)\\
&=S_t\frac{e^{r(T-t)}-1}{r(T-t)}
\end{align}
$$

Do note that, for $x>0$, we have $\frac{e^x-1}{x}>1$. Hence, the expectation is clearly greater than $S_t$. Also, if $r=0$, the expectation becomes $S_t$ as expected.

HTH?

Comment: Thanks for this reply. The math checks out, I think my problem was that I misstated the risk-neutral condition.